# How to remove ' in java script

Tags: javascript

I have problem in removing ' with (blank and no space). Like Kello's to kellos.

I already tried this-

```
str = str.replace(/[\']/g, '');
```

But its not working.

Please help.

Comment: its work take a look at [JsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/nebsnqaf/1/).

Comment: The regular expression could be simplifed to `/'/g` but that would not change the already working code. Please be more specific in describing the problem. Input, expected output, actual wrong output.

Answer (score 1):

It actually does work:

```
var str = 'aa\'bb\'cc';
alert(str.replace(/'/g,'')); // aabbcc
alert(str.replace(/[\']/g,'')); // aabbcc
```

You do not need a character class, you just have to mask it if you use single quotes in JavaScript.

Also, keep in mind that `'` (U+0027) is different from `’` (U+2019) and must be handled separately.

Comment: That's the exact same code as shown by @DeveshAgrawal. How is this supposed to be an answer?

Comment: @Andreas: It is not, please read again carefully. The first statement emphasizes that it already does work. Also, I’m showing a simpler solution that also works while noting that problems may arise from quotes and/or misinterpreted characters that look like an apostrophe.

Comment: The code shown by Devesh already works so this is just a "It works, see...". The "simpler" regular expression doesn't change anything - besides using less characters. And the example in the question has a simple apostroph and not a U+2019. so this part is only a guess which would be a comment.

Comment: @Andreas: Objection again: It very well changes something, i.e. leaving out the character class (making a substantial difference for the regex engine) and a masking backslash, being part of my answer. The remark on similiar apostrophes was not only for the sake of completeness, but very much intended, because the OP’s given string (“Kello’s”) is rather the source of error than the obviously working code, especially when somebody is not absolutely sure about notation _and_ is retyping an example. You’re welcome to flag the question as unanswerable or to produce an improved response yourself.

Comment: What is the difference between `.replace(/'/g, '')` and `.replace(/[\']/g, '')` in respect to the result? Exactly: none. Both replace all `'` with a blank.

Comment: @Andreas: It would be very foolhardy to believe there’s no difference just because results are the same, _especially_ when it comes to regular expressions. Besides, I didn’t say results differ, but I _did_ say they were being differently processed. I produced it as simplification, and obviously you agree with me (suggesting `/'/g` in your comment).

Answer (score 0):

A Kello's

str.replace(/[{\ },{\'}]/g,"");

result      AKellos